# Using a single zip file with FORFILES

Tags: batch-file

I'm attempting to use the command:

```
forfiles.exe -p. -m*.log -d-1 -c"zip -u -m @FILE.zip @FILE"
```

and it does close to what I'm looking for.

I'd like the zip tool or 7z to put everything in one zip file and then date stamp it (name) with today's date.

Thoughts?

Comment: What is `forfiles.exe`? Never heard of it. Also I'm unsure whether I exactly know what you would like to do.

Comment: @jsalonen - Type `FORFILES /?` from the command line to get info. It is mostly useless, except for one very important feature. The `/d` option enables filtering of files based on the last modified date. The OP is using the /d option to select only files that are at least 1 day old.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to run ZIP via CMD when using FORFILES. There should also be a space between each FORFILES option and its value.

You need to select a name for your zip file. I chose "myzip.zip".

I think this will work, but I don't have ZIP, so I can't test.

```
forfiles -p . -m *.log -d -1 -c "cmd /c zip -u -m myzip.zip @FILE"
```

Comment: EDIT - Oops, I forgot to put the `cmd /c` in the actual code. All fixed now.